# VK_xxx in Java for ~ (tilde), ? (question mark), % (percent), | (vert bar) and " (dbl quote)

Tags: java

I am trying to find the `VK_xxx` in `KeyEvent` for all the keys I can type in on my keyboard. I can find most of them, except the above 5. Any idea why these 5 are missing? Should I be using the shift mask for these? If I go that route, can I use shift mask for 2 (`VK_AT`), 3 (`VK_NUMBER_SIGN`), 4 (`VK_DOLLAR`), etc., too?

The context - I am reading a String from a file than contains arbitrary ASCII characters, and trying to have the AWT Robot press and release the VK's to put the string somewhere. Thank you.

Comment: How do I put a bounty on this question?

Comment: Below the comment button, press "start a bounty".

Answer (score 1):

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html

*It states:*
Not all characters have a keycode associated with them. For example, **there is no keycode for the question mark** because there is no keyboard for which it appears on the primary layer.

VK_DEAD_TILDE, VK_QUOTEDBL.

So you have also to capture the charCode event, besides keyReleased.

A bit unportable would be SHIFT+5 etc.

Answer (score 0):

VK_BACK_QUOTE

{
Value: 192
HEX_Value: 0Xc0
CHAR_VALUE:'`'
}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score -1):

I discovered a way, if you press VK_CONTROL,VK_ALT, VK_W you can get a "?" question mark.