# What is the Key code of the key in the image below in JAVA?

Tags: java, swing, keyboard, ascii, keycode

[image]

Exp: key code of '1' in java is VK_1 just like,
What is the Key code of the marked key in the pic in java??

Comment: have you tried `VK_DEAD_TILDE` ? Btw. it's called Tilde ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801427/vk-xxx-in-java-for-tilde-question-mark-percent-vert-bar-and

Comment: Yes it is  VK_DEAD_TILDE.  Refer this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html

Comment: Please note that it will probably not work (tilde is not the primary character on that any key usually!)

Comment: On my keyboard it's `²`...

Comment: VK_DEAD_TILDE did not work. i tried this. So how it will work? what can i do so that it works? @ParkerHalo

Answer (score 1):

According to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html it's:

```
VK_DEAD_TILDE
```

At least in Java 7.  I'm not sure about Java 8.

Hope this helped!

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.